# Fujitsu scansnap ix1400 USB scanner not recognized by Ubuntu

Tags: scanner

My Fujitsu Scansnap IX1400 is not recognized by Ubuntu. The troubleshooting procedure from Sane didn't help? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Watch the terminal command `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the scanner. Read `man journalctl`. Scanners are handled through SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy), start with `man -k sane`. Run `sane-find-scanner`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: sane-find-scanner returned following comment: "could not open USB device 0x04c5/0x1630 at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)". This is the data of my scanner Fujitsu Scansnap IX1400

Comment: Try `sudo sane-find-scanner` and see my answer below.

Answer (score -2):

Many device access problems are permission problems, and can be resolved through group membership changes.

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 -l /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 -l /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
# change to your device name 
device="/dev/YourDevice"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.